# Varios proyectos desde una solución existente

Tags: visual-studio-2015, control-de-versiones

Tengo una solución web programada en C#, con archivos aspx y algunas dll. Usa MSSQL Server. Aplicaciones o grupos de aplicaciones están ordenadas en distintos directorios, hay unos seis de estos. Quiero poner todo esto en el control de versiones de Team Foundation. Creé una solución vacía en Visual Studio, con la intención de agregar todos estos archivos existentes, algo que debo hacer previamente a poner el código en el repositorio. A efectos de organizar el control de código, creo que sería conveniente dividir esta solución en varios proyectos distintos, pues hay aplicaciones que probablemente no se toquen más o incluso se quiten en un futuro próximo. **No encuentro el modo de crear una solución con varios proyectos a partir de los archivos existentes. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto, utilizando *Visual Studio 2015*?** (Si alguien quiere sugerirme la inconveniencia de mi estrategia, acepto argumentos al respecto.)

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de entender muy bien la arquitectura que tienes ahora. De todas formas, puedes añadir los proyectos vacíos y después mover las clases que quieras a estos proyectos. Eso si, tendrás que añadir estas referencias al proyecto que use estas clases.